# Convert from VMWare to Hyper-V

Tags: converters, vmware, hyper-v

Deleted my original question in favor of what is a better question, and an answer to go with it, as my understanding of the problem I was asking is completely changed now:

How to convert from VMWare to Hyper-V? This is a single VM, not managed by any kind of management software like VMWare ESX.

Answer (score 0):

Before activating Hyper-V

1. Uninstall VMWare Tools from your VM.
2. Then if your VMs have a series of files that are sequential, and end
   with .VMDK, there is a utility that comes with VMWare to combine
   those back into a single VM file. It is called vdiskmanager.  See [this
   site](http://vmexpo.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/how-to-merge-multiple-vmdks-into-single-vmdk/) for instructions on how to do that (note that I am not the
   author of that site, but the directions seem to work just fine).
3. After this is done, find a standalone vmware to hyper-v converter
   software (there are several - I choose not to point any out since
   I'm agnostic about them, and I haven't worked with most of them, but
   you can do a simple search for vmware to hyper-v converter
   standalone) - What this is doing is simply changing the format from VMDK to VHD (or VHDX).
4. Once that is done, activate Hyper-V, reboot, bring up the Hyper-V
   manager, and follow the steps for importing a VM. At this point, you
   should be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the trickiest part of converting a VMWare VM to Hyper-V VM is dealing with snapshots. In my case, I didn't want all snapshots that had been created in the VMWare VM, but only one particular snapshot. In earlier attempts using the original vmdk file as the source, the conversion always seem use the earliest snapshot; while what I wanted was a later snapshot. In the end this procedure worked reliably for me:

1. Uninstall VMWare tools from the VM.
2. In VMWare, clone the VM, specifying the desired snapshot.
3. Download the "Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter 3.1" msi from Microsoft and run the installer.
4. Start powershell with administrative privileges, and run the commands:

   import-module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter\MvmcCmdlet.psd1'

   ConvertTo-MvmcVirtualHardDisk -SourceLiteralPath [cloned.vmdk] -VhdType DynamicHardDisk -VhdFormat vhdx -DestinationLiteralPath [result folder]

Then use the Hyper-V host to create a new VM using vhdx file resulting from the conversion as the disk (instead of creating a new disk).